Is there a way to find the inverse of a higher order function?
Let's say I have a higher order function that repeats a function twice:
const twice = f => x => f(f(x))

Is there any way I can write a function where I input the result of an instance of evaluation of twice, and it can return f?
const find_f (twice, result) => f

I have experimented with a lot of versions but can't seem to find a way to "extract" f from the twice function.

Are you asking this in terms of a computation question or in terms of a Javascript API/syntax question? I.e., are you trying to get a reference to the actual f which may somehow be retained in twice? Or are you asking to reverse engineer the computation f does, given result as the input? If the latter: no; certainly not for all possible functions. If the former: probably also no.

To my best knowledge, you can't access the actual values closed over by a function object, so no.
If you're at the liberty to change twice:


const twice = f => Object.assign(x => f(f(x)), {f});

const g = x => x * 4;
const gg = twice(g);
console.log(gg(9));
console.log(gg.f);



